# Resetting environment path using Ubuntu bash on Windows

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have attempted to prioritize the environment path by changing the .bashrc by "/mnt/c/Users/michaelvolk/anaconda3". As you can see from the image this is where my updated vers[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOcPE.png)ion of python.exe is located. I have also attempted to add "/mnt/c/Users/michaelvolk/anaconda3/Scripts" which is where pip.exe is located. For some reason "/usr/bin" still has priority even though it is listed after the paths I added. Can anyone help provide advice for changing the environment path so the newest version of python can be found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 is prioritized because `/usr/bin/python` is the first **Linux binary** in your `$PATH` inside the WSL distribution and directory you've added only contains native **Windows binaries**. WSL doesn't take in account native Windows binaries unless executed explicitly with `.exe` extension (if you execute `python.exe` that should run binary you are pointing at in your screenshot). If you want to use Windows distribution of Anaconda and Python with WSL you can do that by running commands with `.exe` extension. But then you cannot use any Linux-isms in it (you will need to use `C:\...\` paths inside your notebooks and things installed by `pip` in WSL won't be available because **Windows versions** has no idea about WSL and Linux).

If you want to fully leverage WSL as a Linux distribution then you need to install a [**Linux version** of Anaconda](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-a-data-science-environment-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-c4b390803dd) distribution inside the WSL. Then when you'll extend `$PATH` to point to it (or source-in the environment file provided by installer) proper **Linux binaries** will be used. If you store your notebooks and data on C: drive (`/mnt/c/` in WSL) you can reach them with Windows tools (e.g. editor) too.